# rails + sidekiq specific date and time job

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can we add job to sidekiq using rails to a specific date and time using db time, I want to send emails when an appointment time comes, so what will be the best approach to do that?

Comment: I found the solution, once an appointment is created, taking out the difference from current time and convert it in hours and then, add that time to new job which will be executed after the hours that are set.


Example: 
`time = TimeDifference(Time.now - appointment_time).in_hours`
`AppointmentsWorker.perform_in(time.hours)`

Answer (score 4):

You might refer to the native Active Job API introduce in rails 4.2 (which come in front of Sidekiq).

You build job with the rails API, you specify in conf file that you use sidekiq, and rails will put the job in sidekiq.

Advantages : You can switch to another enqueuing gem, easier to delay job at a specific date, you can perform after_action, which are normally in the professional version of Sidekiq.

See the tutorial to learn more about it : http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html

A quick example :

`# Enqueue a job to be performed tomorrow at noon.
MyJob.set(wait_until: Date.tomorrow.noon).perform_later(record)`

Hope it help

Comment: @user1735921 I just leave this snippet here. Write this code in the Job(Worker) class `MyMailer.send_email(options).deliver_later(wait_until: Date.tomorrow.noon)`

Answer (score 1):

Attach an appointment date (or even better a specific appointment notification datetime) to the appointment model.

Then have a background job queued every minute that checks for all the unsent notifications for close events (for instance events where the appointment notification is lower than 1 minute in the future and not sent yet) and for each appointment queue an email to be sent.

You may want to use `sidekiq` to queue the emails, and a cron system such as `clockwork` to enqueue a task on `sidekiq` to check every minute for notifications to be sent.